Delete the Short description through CSV
We want to delete the Short description through CSV - Import.
We are using below format.

Issue :
But the Short description is not deleting. But if i keep any other text below the short_description, than the value is updating. but i want to delete the existing value instead of replacing.

If you want to PN13087 sku short_description blank right? If yes then only you need to pass blank . check SS. https://prnt.sc/LEOd0RBINvC-

@MohitPatel thankyou, please post it as answer

You can add like as below SS. It will delete short_description from the product.

THANKS.

both the answers are correct.
You can also use comments instead of passing any values to the field. By this way, unnecessary space/tags won't be assigned as a value.
e.g,
<!-- no short desc -->


Please format your answer correctly. Use the ` character to show code.

Thankyou so much

Mohit answer is correct, but it might impact the frontend layout. Therefore, it's better to insert a blank space in the CSV column.


thankyou Ahsan. That's Nice idea
